# DRM on smartphones (Android, iOS, etc.)

Tags: android, ios, encryption, encoding, drm

We have to develop a DRM component for audio/video streaming for various mobile platforms. The DRM server supplier is currently unknown as well as the streaming protocol format (assumption is HLS or RTSP).

Do you have idea what has to be developed on the client side? I think even we do not have the server ready we can start doing a lot of things in advance.

BR
SteN

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to lock down at least some component of the DRM implementation. There are a lot of vendors coming out now with cross platform (iOS & Android) solutions. I don't think RTSP is viable as this type of streaming hasn't been implemented with encryption as it was only used when the operator/carrier did the streaming themselves directly to the handsets. There are many vendors with HLS support and Playready (microsoft smooth streaming) appears to be getting hold on multiple devices also. Unfortunately you have to look at point solutions and may not be able to work generically across all devices on day one unless you completely build the DRM into your application and hand off to the native media player upon playback. If you do a few google searches around DRM android/ios you will find many options.

Comment: Hi, the plan is to choose one vendor (e.g. Discretix, Vertimatrix, etc.), which is providing the DRM solution and use their DRM server together with selected streaming server and then program the client part on our own. The question intention was - what we should implement on the client side, if we go e.g. with HLS? If it can be said that e.g. we need to exchange keys, use them for getting password for e.g. AES, which we will use to decode HLS .ts chunks, which we will then stream to the built-in player... Knowledge like this, i.e. list of steps we should do is what we are missing.